# Why can't I see the structure of the tables into phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

it's a very long time I used xampp and I've always the same problem. When I use PhpMyAdmin and click on the structure of a table I see an error message like this:

[image]

the translation of this message is: Processing and request error / Error code:200 / Error message: OK

Do someone know the problem? I can't see any structure but I need to see it. With prompt it's all ok but using phpmyadmin no. Why? Can someone help me?

Comment: have you seen the apache log or your webserver log?

Comment: Good thing I understand Italian. *No lo so, scusi.*

Comment: @Webster yes but nothing tell me the problem.. but if it's important I use win 10.

Comment: Could you tell me which phpMyAdmin version that is? You can see it on the main phpMyAdmin page, on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys thank you to all but I solved the problem. 
It's referred to the Italian localization. 
I changed the language with english and the problem is solved.

The usual luck of the italians.
Thanks so much!!

Comment: Ah, benissimo!! è molto fortunata per te.